# Get first text of first span in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can get first text of first span in jQuery.

Expect result: `abc` but it give me `abc abc2`. How can I do it?

```js
console.log($("#x1:first").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="x1">abc<span>abc2</span></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to return only the text node:

```js
var text = $('#x1').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3; // text node
}).text();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="x1">abc<span>abc2</span></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the text

**Using Javascript with [firstChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) & [nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue):**

```js
const text = document.getElementById("x1").firstChild.nodeValue;
console.log( text );
```

```html
<span id="x1">abc<span>abc2</span></span>
```

**Using jQuery with [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) & [get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/):**

```js
const text = $("#x1").contents().get(0).nodeValue;
console.log( text );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="x1">abc<span>abc2</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($("#x1:first").clone().children().remove().end().text());


// .children() ->  select all the child elements
// .remove()   ->  remove all the child elements
// .end()      ->  again go back to parent element
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="x1">abc<span>abc2</span></span>
```

**Note:** `.clone()` is important here, otherwise actual element will be modified.